# Is there any document that maps the status codes returned in Client.StateChanged Event with their intended purpose?

Tags: lync, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/lync-wpf/jj275501(v%3doffice.15)

I get the status changed event from the lync sdk along with the status code -2131885944 
I know the old state and the new state.
But my question is is there any documentation that lets me know what this specific status code means?

I searched many links ,but all I got is Lync system platform  codes

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/lync-platform-status-codes) is the best document you'll find - it does cover a lot of the status codes you're likely to see in the client SDK, but unfortunately it's not comprehensive. For example, it doesn't include your status code above. I can't find anything that specifically covers the status code for StateChanged, including in the SDK source code.